# Display drop down box on product front end

Tags: configurable-product-options

I want to add a drop down box that allows the customer to specify what we should do if an item doesn't have the specified amount **(Ship what you have, Cancel item, or Contact me).**

I would like to display this on the product page and have the info captured with their order.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Easiest way, You can create custom option for product. It will show with each product. This option can be seen in admin too.